# A finite graph G is $d$-regular if, and only if, its adjacency matrix has the eigenvalue $λ = d$

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Show that a graph $G$ ﬁnite with $n$ vertices is $d$-regular if, and only if, the vector with all the coordinates equals to 1 is  eigenvetor from eigenvalue $λ = d$  from the  adjacency matrix
 $A$ from the graph $G$.
The question itself was a little confused for me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funny thing, I just learned this myself this week. It is proposition 3 on page 2 of [these excellent lecture notes by Padraic Bartlett](http://math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/mathcamp_2011/spectral_GT/MC2011_spectral_GT_wk3_day3.pdf). [The entire set of lecture notes on spectral graph theory is here](http://math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/mathcamp_2011/mathcamp_2011.html).

(I promised in 2012 to write up the proof here, but I hereby retract that promise. I would not be able to improve upon Brian Scott's writeup elsewhere in this thread.)

Comment: Today was my test...this question was in it....

Comment: @MarylinM.J I hope you passed!

Comment: @ Mark Dominus I took Ten!!!!

Comment: @HipsterMathematician Congratulations!

Answer (score 10):

Suppose that $G$ is $d$-regular. Then every vertex of $G$ is adjacent to $d$ other vertices, so each row of its adjacency matrix $A$ will have $d$ $1$’s and $n-d$ $0$’s. Let

$$A=\pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}&\dots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\dots&a_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\dots&a_{nn}}\;,$$

and $\vec v$ be the $n\times 1$ vector whose entries are all $1$:

$$\vec v=\pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\1}\;.$$

The product $\vec u=A\vec v$ is an $n\times 1$ vector whose $i$-th entry is $$u_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}\cdot1=a_{i1}+a_{i2}+\ldots+a_{in}\;.$$ Since $d$ of the numbers $a_{i1},\dots,a_{in}$ are $1$ and the rest are $0$, $u_i=d$ for every $i$. Thus, $$\vec u=\pmatrix{d\\d\\\vdots\\d}=d\vec v\;.$$ That is, $A\vec v=d\vec v$, so by definition $\vec v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $d$.

To show the other direction, you can try to reverse this argument; that works. Alternatively, you can assume that $G$ is **not** $d$-regular and show that $\vec v$ is **not** an eigenvector for an eigenvalue $d$; that also works and may be even easier.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: They don't know a damn thing to explain.