# Adjacency Matrix of d-regular graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, network, adjacency-matrix

"If  is the adjacency matrix of a -regular graph, then any row of  contains exactly  1’s.
Thus, the vector 1=1,1,…,1 is an eigenvector of  with eigenvalue ."

How do we know that only having rows with exactly  1's will give us an eigenvector of (1,1...,1)?

Thanks!

Comment: "Thus, the vector 1..." What did you mean by '1'? Also, if possible next time, rewrite the math symbols/equations using MathJax instead of copying/pasting the font.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A finite graph G is $d$-regular if, and only if, its adjacency matrix has the eigenvalue $λ = d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150592/a-finite-graph-g-is-d-regular-if-and-only-if-its-adjacency-matrix-has-the-ei)